# Exception thrown when trying to access a protected variable from a child class after a dynamic casting

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

I am trying to learn about dynamic casting in C++.

So I have developed 2 classes to test some things related to dynamic casting:

```
class Entity {
protected:
    int x = 10;
public:
    virtual void f1() { cout << "f1 from Entity class" << endl; }
};

class Player : public Entity {
public:
    void f1() { cout << "f1 from Player class" << endl; }
    int f2() { return x; }
    void f3() { cout << "f3 from Player class" << endl; }
};
```

The method `f2()` returns x that is defined in the Parent Class `Entity`.

And here is the `main`:

```
int main() {
    Entity* e = new Entity;

    Player* p = dynamic_cast<Player*>(e);
    cout << p->f2() << endl;

    
    //the program prints : "p is not null"
    if(p == nullptr)
        cout << "p is null";
    else
        cout << "p is not null";

    return 0;
}
```

An exception is thrown when calling `p->f2()`, specifically on line `return x;` and it says:

> Exception thrown: read access violation.
> this was nullptr.

The strange thing here is that `x` is a protected variable, so it must exist at
Entity and Player objects, but after the dynamic casting from Entity to Player, the new object can not access it.

So what is the exception reason?

**Note: When doing static casting instead of dynamic, `p->f2()` gives 10 normally**

Comment: You can't cast `e` to a `Player*`, it's not the correct type

Comment: Re: "after the dynamic casting ... the new object" -- there is no new object. The dynamic cast creates a new **pointer** that points at the original object if the cast succeeded. In this case the cast failed, and the pointer is a null pointer. That's what the error message is telling you with "this was nullptr".

Comment: The pointer itself (p variable) is not null, I have added the test to the main, please refer to it.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, pointer is very clearly null: https://godbolt.org/z/M81jP4a51

Comment: Although checking the pointer *after* you dereference it is also *undefined behavior*, so your "test" was very likely wrong

Comment: @UnholySheep I am working on visual studio, the project type is C++ console application, and it gives me "p is not null", may that affect the result?

Comment: As I said, the way your `main` is written currently it will invoked *undefined behavior*, so the result of that check is meaningless. You need to remove the call to `p->f2()` (or only call it within the `else` block)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dynamic_cast` will never lie. It checks the runtime type of the object to see if it matches the `T` gi8ven in the `dynamic_cast<T>`. You created an instance of the `Entity` base class. The runtime type of this object is `Entity` because *that's what you created*.

`dynamic_cast` knows the runtime type of the object, so it knows `dynamic_cast<Player*>` cannot work since the object isn't a `Player` object. Therefore, it returns `nullptr`.

`static_cast` doesn't know if the object is a `Player` or not; it *assumes* that it is and returns a pointer to that object if it is there. But since it's not there, any attempt to use the result of the `static_cast` yields undefined behavior.

Which just so happens to do what you want, but there's no guarantee of that.

Comment: I agree with all that you have said. But I have one point, I have added the `f3()` method to the `Player` class. Now when calling p->f3() instead of p->f2() it works normally and prints "f3 from Player class", could you please explain why?

Comment: @XY: What does it matter? You're using `->` on a *null pointer*. Even if it "works", it's still undefined behavior, so stop doing it.